# Subdomain mapping

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, azure-storage, cname

I have shifted my **word press** blog on my website as its sub domain, but internal pages are still showing old blog's **URL**. 
how can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Read [Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress), the canonical document on how to move a Wordpress blog in the Codex, especially item 10.

> Existing image/media links uploaded media will refer to the old folder and must be updated with the new location. You can do this with the [Velvet Blues Update URLs plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/), or with a [search and replace tool](http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/), or manually in your SQL database, by following the instructions at [Tamba2's Tutorial "Moving your weblog inside your PC".](http://www.tamba2.org.uk/wordpress/move3)